# How can i --"Start Intent by GridView item Click" (not image)

Tags: gridview, android-intent, android-activity

I want to start every Intent that remains under my `src`. They are named as `One.java`, `Two.java` and so on.

Here is my java code, but after clicking on a GridView item, it is opening the same Intent window, not the `One.java` or `Two.java` activity.

- MyActivity.java:

  ```
  import android.app.Activity;
  import android.content.Intent;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
  import android.widget.AdapterView;
  import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
  import android.widget.GridView;
  public class MyActivity extends Activity {  

  static final String[] numbers = new String[] { "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six",  "Seven"  };

  @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {      
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.myactivity);

          GridView gv = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);

          ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, numbers);

          gv.setAdapter(adapter);
          gv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
          public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,int position, long id) {
                  Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyActivity.class);
                  i.putExtra("id", position);
                  startActivity(i);
              }
          });
      }
  }
  ```

This will help:

http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-gridview-example/ and

[Android Gridview - Need to open different intents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6024374/android-gridview-need-to-open-different-intents?rq=1)

Answer (score 4):

**Here is an example how you can start intent for every position in the grid view :**

```
gv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {


            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,int position, long id) {

                switch (position) {
                case 0:

                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyActivity.class);
                    i.putExtra("id", position);
                    startActivity(i);
                    break;

                case 1:
                    //Use some different intent here
                    Intent j = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyActivity.class);
                    j.putExtra("id", position);
                    startActivity(j);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    //Use some different intent here
                    Intent k = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyActivity.class);
                    k.putExtra("id", position);
                    startActivity(k);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    //Use some different intent here
                    Intent l = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyActivity.class);
                    l.putExtra("id", position);
                    startActivity(l);
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
                }



            }
            });
```

I hope this is what you are looking for.