# How To Load Separate Pages In Android Gridview While Clicking Blocks or Items?

Tags: android, gridview

I want to load separate pages while clicking on Gridview blocks. By clicking Gridview Items , i want to load a full page that will be contained image or some description. I have set the gridview basic settings. Is it possible or how can i do that for a descriptive page viewing while clicking gridview blocks-items in android.

```
package com.android20.personalities;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.app.Activity;

 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    GridView gv = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);

    gv.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

    gv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) 
        {


        }

    });

   }

   }
```

The Java class of ImageAdapter

```
package com.android20.personalities;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

 Context imgCntxt;   


public ImageAdapter(Context c) 
{
            this.imgCntxt= c;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return images.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ImageView imgview;

    if(convertView==null)
    {
        imgview = new ImageView(imgCntxt);

        imgview.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
    }

    else

    {
        imgview = (ImageView) convertView;
    }

    imgview.setImageResource(images[position]);

    return imgview;

 }


public Integer[] images =
    {

        R.drawable.image1, 
        R.drawable.image2,
        R.drawable.image3, 
        R.drawable.image4, 
        R.drawable.image5,
        R.drawable.image6, 
        R.drawable.image7, 
        R.drawable.image8,
        R.drawable.image9,
        R.drawable.image10

    };

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Onclick of gridview item you can start new activity load content by passing griditem position., or by checking position add content in intent

Comment: how to set it for different pages from gridview items

Comment: If only content is different & page layout is same you can call same activity each time and pass girditem position of fetch griditem text and compare it in activity.And show content accordingly.

Comment: i want to set different pages while clicking different grid items

Comment: if no. page count is more you can maintain it in array or arraylist and in loop you can start that page

Answer (score 0):

you can add onClickListner in Image adapter itself and do the stuff in your coding to go to other activity with position and write code for showing image with full screen .
Check this might be helpful http://www.androidhive.info/2013/09/android-fullscreen-image-slider-with-swipe-and-pinch-zoom-gestures/

Comment: i want to load a specific page for specific gridview item, thanks

Comment: switch (position) {
case 0:
// start one activity
break;
case 1:
// start another activity
break;

Comment: You can open different activity for different position using switch case .

Comment: Refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6024374/android-gridview-need-to-open-different-intents